# Encrypting Tools other than aspnet_regiis to encrypt App.config Connection String

Tags: c#, winforms, encryption

I know that there are already a lot of SO posts regarding encryption of connection string in app.config but I'm hoping that there are some methods or built in library in `C#` other than `aspnet_regiis` to encrypt .

My Specification:

- Desktop application will be distributed to users
- Cannot use web service. If you will ask why, then it is more on server Issues.
- App.config contains the connection string for the MYSQL server

Comment: This might help you. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Dr.Stitch I'm currently on researching process, do you know if its applicable to use WCF to connect into MYSQL?

Comment: I think so. I haven't tried it to desktop application.